# avoid regex greediness

Tags: c++

Basic regex question.

By default, regular expression are greedy, it seems. For e.g. below code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const std::string t = "*1 abc";
  std::smatch match;
  std::regex rgxx("\\*(\\d+?)\\s+(.+?)$");
  bool matched1 = std::regex_search(t.begin(), t.end(), match, rgxx);
  std::cout << "Matched size " << match.size() << std::endl;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < match.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i << " match " << match[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This will produce an output of:

```
Matched size 3
**0 match *1 abc**
1 match 1
2 match abc
```

As an general regular expression writer, I would expected only

```
1 match 1
2 match abc
```

to come. First match is coming because of regex greediness, I think. How is it avoidable?

Answer (score 1):

From [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search): `match[0]` is not the result of greedy evaluation, but is the range of the entire match. The match elements `[1, n)` are the capture groups.

Here's in illustration of what the match results mean:

```
regex     "hello ([\\w]+)"

string   = "Oh, hello John!"
match[0] =     "hello John"   // matches the whole regex above
match[1] =           "John"   // the first capture group
```

Comment: How can you avoid it then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, `regex_search` is designed to find a match, and `match[0]` *is* that match. It might be more clear if you had a regex that only matched the middle of a string. But, if you don't care about the match and just want the capture groups, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one match. That match has 2 "marked subexpressions", because that's what the regex specifies. You don't have multiple matches of that regex.

From [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

> `m.size()`:    number of marked subexpressions plus 1, that is, `1+rgxx.mark_count()`

If you are looking for multiple matches, use [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)